# Substr more than one value in a Oracle CLOB column

Tags: sql, xml, plsql, oracle11g, clob

I have a clob column in a database table which has a lot of XML text. I'm trying to grab all the Exceptions from the clob by using SQL or PL/SQL, the exceptions come under an XML tab of ExceptionList as you can see below. How would I just get the text string "**Both HPI Make and HPI Category have to be entered - one cannot exist without the other**" from the below example in the clob and also get the other Exception descriptions "**Exception List must be empty**","**AgreementNumber must not be supplied**","**IntroducerCode or Name is invalid**" and "**SupplierCode or Name invalid. Must exist on pancredit**" which are the Exception Descriptions. There can be other exceptions but I'm just trying to get all the exception descriptions (i.e. substr anything between the XML tab tns:Description and </tns:Description>) in the clob.

Would I do this in an PL/SQL LOOP or could this be done using SQL?

```
<tns:ExceptionList>
      <tns:Exception>
        <tns:Description>Both HPI Make and HPI Category have to be entered - one cannot exist without the other.
</tns:Description>
      </tns:Exception>
      <tns:Exception>
        <tns:Description>Exception List must be empty</tns:Description>
      </tns:Exception>
      <tns:Exception>
        <tns:Description>AgreementNumber must not be supplied</tns:Description>
      </tns:Exception>
      <tns:Exception>
        <tns:Description>IntroducerCode or Name is invalid</tns:Description>
      </tns:Exception>
      <tns:Exception>
        <tns:Description>SupplierCode or Name invalid. Must exist on pancredit.</tns:Description>
      </tns:Exception>
    </tns:ExceptionList>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have XML then treat is as XML, don't try to extract data from it using substrings. Presumably this is a fragment of a larger document that has parent nodes and declares the `tns` namespace; so you can do:

```
select x.description
from your_table t
cross apply xmltable(
  xmlnamespaces('https://some/url' as "tns"),
  '//tns:ExceptionList/tns:Exception'
  passing xmltype(t.your_clob)
  columns description path 'tns:Description'
) x
```

| DESCRIPTION |
| --- |
| Both HPI Make and HPI Category have to be entered - one cannot exist without the other.<br> |
| Exception List must be empty |
| AgreementNumber must not be supplied |
| IntroducerCode or Name is invalid |
| SupplierCode or Name invalid. Must exist on pancredit. |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=cb05d6a0facc419c0bb89f04b0bb9c48)

Comment: @ShaunKinnair - I've just noticed you tagged the question with Oracle 11g, which wouldn't recognise `cross apply` - if you are on an old version you can use `cross join` instead. Otherwise you can remove that tag, or change it to just [oracle].